# rplidar_ros step by step for get map

Tags: ros, catkin, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have a simple question ... i want to get map from RPLidar laser scan but i get confused in google and for now i don't know how i can implement that

i install ros using below **command**

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

and then run below command for define ros directory and commands for ubuntu(14.04) and it's ok(before that commands not define in terminal such as roscd,roscore,...)

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

after this step i clone(donwload) ros_rplidar from this web page [ https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros ] , in this page robopeak prepare a tutorial of **How to build rplidar ros package** but i don't know what is catkin's workspace and why catkin_make don't work for me ? is there any good tutorial about this in step by step because i can't find that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258579/rplidar_ros-step-by-step-for-get-map/) by [saeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/29932/saeed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
you need to setup a Catkin workspace, there are a list of tutorials for how to use, and setup catkin.

http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials

Once you have done this, you can clone the git repo for Rplidar_ros into '~/catkin_ws/src' folder for example, and then run catkin_make from '~/catkin_ws' folder to build it.

---

Originally posted by [Vairn](https://answers.ros.org/users/29989/vairn/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0